# Programmatically created grouped table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a grouped table view & I had a edit button in the title bar & I can able to navigate to other page on click of every row  after pressing edit button

now by using following code I have designed the grouped table view programmatically but now edit button is not working on click of a row (after pressing edit) it's not navigating
how can I fix this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 415)style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: ya it worked thank u,,but while running the app i am getting this waring at console how can i fix this                                   WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in <DetailViewController: 0x4e30dc0>.  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

@Ruben is right. Set the delegate of the tableView and Implement the `UITableViewDelegate` methods

Answer (score 0):

Side note - although developers do often assign the view controller as the datasource and delegate of a UITableView, you may want to consider farming these responsibilities out to another object.

UIViewController subclasses do have a habit of becoming so-called "god" classes, taking on lots of responsibilities (hence violating the Single Responsibility Principle) and also making them difficult to unit test.